# Convert hexadecimal string to hexadecimal type

Tags: javascript, hex

I've got a JSON file in which I need to pass some hexidecimal values. Unfortunately, hex is not a valid type in JSON, so I have to include the hex as a string. I want to convert the string back to hex on the other side, but can't find a way to do that.

An example is this JSON:

```
{ address: "0x2D" }
```

On the other end, I need to pass `0x2D` as a value

```
writeBytes(0x2D);
```

Comment: Use `parseInt` method

Comment: @hindmost parseInt returns the integer, not hexidecimal

Comment: Any [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) is a (integer) number. The difference is only in [radix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix) (`16` for hexadecimal, `10` for decimal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
parseInt("0x2D", 16)
```

Does this method will be good for you?

```
console.log('0x' + parseInt("0x2D", 16).toString(16))
```

for checking

Comment: the .toString method at the end to me means that this return `"0x2D"`, not `0x2D`

Comment: it does. Quotes isn't part of value

Comment: You are correct, sorry it took so long to respond, I used 'typof' to show your working code. http://jsfiddle.net/w7c3Lh00/